# Angular 7 Filter Dropdown values

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two mat-select dropdown.
In first Dropdown I have value like a,b,c,d
In second Dropdown I have same value like a,b,c,d

**Requirement**

When I select 1st dropdown than selected value from first dropdown should not appear in Second Dropdown and also vice versa.
For example I have selected 'b' value in first dropdown than in second dropdown 'b' should not be present only a,c,d should be present.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-filter-nayx2k?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

From above stackblitz I am able to filter values but other dropdown values default values is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to build your model according to your requirements. You currently have 2 drop downs, but only one list driving them both.

I would instead create an array for each select and bind the selected values to a property for each dropdown. It then becomes fairly simple to rebuild the arrays when a value changes.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected1" (selectionChange)="change1()" placeholder="Custom placeholder">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filtered1" [value]="item.id">
      {{item.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<br>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected2" (selectionChange)="change2()" placeholder="Using array of objects">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filtered2" [value]="item.id">
      {{item.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
filtered1: {}[];
filtered2: {}[];
selected1: number;
selected2: number;

private options = [
  { 
    id: 0, 
    name: 'a' 
  }, 
  { 
    id: 1, 
    name: 'b' 
  },
  { 
    id: 2, 
    name: 'c' 
  },
  { 
    id: 3, 
    name: 'd' 
  }
];

ngOnInit() {
  this.selected1 = this.options[0].id;
  this.selected2 = this.options[1].id;

  this.change1();
  this.change2();
}

change1() {
  this.filtered2 = this.options.filter(x => x.id !== this.selected1);
}    

change2() {
  this.filtered1 = this.options.filter(x => x.id !== this.selected2);
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-filter-2usqw5

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

Component

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
    dropdownOne: string;
    dropdownTwo: string;
    public variables2 = [
      { 
       id: 0, 
       name: 'a' 
      }, 
      { 
        id: 1, 
        name: 'b' 
      },
      { 
        id: 2, 
        name: 'c' 
      },
      { 
        id: 3, 
        name: 'd' 
      }
      ];


    public filteredList5 = this.variables2.slice();

    change(e){
    }
}
```

Template

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="dropdownOne" (selectionChange)="change($event)" placeholder="Custom placeholder">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of filteredList5">
      <ng-container *ngIf="item != dropdownTwo">
        <mat-option [value]="item">
          {{item.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<br>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="dropdownTwo" (selectionChange)="change($event)" placeholder="Using array of objects">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of filteredList5">
      <ng-container *ngIf="item != dropdownOne">
        <mat-option [value]="item">
          {{item.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The values from dropdown lists are bound to variables `dropdownOne` and `dropdownTwo`. And in the options loop, check if the option's value is not equal to the selected value of the other dropdown before displaying it. Since we check the item before displaying, the filter could be removed from the change event handler.

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-filter-9emmls)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this demo You operate on the same array that's why it was not working

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-filter-wmlnsb

Output: https://mat-select-filter-wmlnsb.stackblitz.io